# difficulty in conversion from intern to permanent

Tags: hiring-process

I am recently graduated from college, and started an internship at an government organization in California. I have been working there for about 4 months out of 6 since an intern can only work up to 6 months. If I didn't get hired, I will be out too. About last month, I have talked to my mentor and the CIO about the hiring process. They keep telling me that "we are working on it". They don't specifically tell what will happen in two months. Should I ask them again about the hiring process? Should I talk to HR?

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

"We are working on it" usually means one of two things.

1. We are *not* working on it. But don't want to explicitly tell you - otherwise you might leave now.
2. We *are* working on it. But we have a really bureaucratic company and this will take a while.

Never go to your manager with a problem. Always approach with a solution, or offer of help.

- "I'm really interested in this job - *what can I do to help speed up the process?*"
- "I'd really like a career in this industry. *Can I provide you with any information which will improve my application?*"
- "I'm not sure how far along the process is. *Would you like me to check with HR to see if I can move it along?*"

And, to be on the safe side, start looking for another full time role.  If they can't handle something as simple as an internal recruitment, they may not be the company for you.

Comment: Since this is a government agency, we are working on it can also mean, we want you and are trying to get you but there are budget considerations (espcially ones causing hiring freezes like last year's government shutdown) that we haven't figured out a way around yet. In amy event, if they can't assure you of a job in two months, it is time to start looking.

Comment: Huge agreement on the list of things you should say. I've worked city government before, and trust me the funds and bureaucracy move at such an intolerably slow speed it's mind boggling, but a lot of the time having someone with an agenda pushing it along speeds things up. You have an agenda (get hired) see if your boss has any ideas how you can get things moving along.

Answer (score 0):

You are entitled to ask about anything that you don't understand about the hiring process and about whatever aspect of the hiring process that's unclear to you. If you have questions you want to ask to HR, ask away.

The fact that you are asking "Should I" creates the perception that you have only a vague idea what you want to ask and that you are hesitating about asking because you have only a vague idea what you want to ask. It's not "should I ask them again?" but "what should I ask?".